# Need to send Whatsapp Messages from Salesforce - Apex Code

Tags: triggers, salesforce, whatsapp, apex

I am doing a proof of concept to find a way to make callouts from Apex code to send automated Whatsapp messages/communications from Salesforce to our customers at difference points of time in Sales life cycle (ex: one at lead conversion, one when a payment is received etc).

My assumption here is to send these messages via triggers. Only thing is i am not able to figure out the correct approach to start with. I did see an example online which is using middleware apps like twilio, weboxapp to convey the messages to Whatsapp servers. Is there a way these communications could be sent directly? Any leads are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a fairly new integration set up between Salesforce and WhatsApp. There's a good write up in the first link below, and then documentation from Salesforce in the 2nd link. I'd start by looking through there because it might help solve your requirements much more easily. I believe that Whatsapp's APIs are private and need to be accessed through an approved partner.

https://www.wearemarketing.com/blog/salesforce-whatsapp-integration-release.html

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.messaging_set_up_whatsapp.htm&type=5